# Show that $u_x(x,0)=0$ for inhomogeneous wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have the PDE $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}+F(x,t)$ with initial conditions $u(x,0)=0$ and $u_t(x,0)=0$ where the solution is assumed to be $u(x,t)=v(\zeta,\mu)$ where $\zeta=x-ct$ and $\mu=x+ct$. The first part of a question for one mark (so it must be really simple) says show that $u_x(x,0)=0$. So $u_x(x,t)=v_{\zeta}(\zeta,\mu)+v_{\mu}(\zeta,\mu)$ but from this I can't see how $u_x(x,0)=0$.

It makes sense intuitively that $u_x(x,0)=0$ from the initial conditions, but not sure how to show it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t = 0 \implies \zeta = \mu$ so the first boundary condition translates to

$$u(x,0) = 0 \implies u(\zeta,\zeta) = 0$$

Then taking the derivative on both sides we get that

$$u_\zeta(\zeta,\zeta) + u_\mu(\zeta, \zeta) = 0 \implies u_x(x,0) = 0$$